# Swift string formula into a real calculation

Tags: ios, swift

I have several formulas stored in a Plist such as A * B. I'm trying to figure out how I could take this formula currently stored as a string in a Plist and use it as an actual calculation formula. I tried going the route of making the formula to \(A) * \(B) and then setting A and B before trying to use the formula but it did not work. Any suggestions?

example

```
let A = 5
let B = 2

println (formula)
```

actually printed out "\(A) * \(B)"

Comment: You're going to have to write an entire string formula parser for this... or see if one exists already that meets your needs.  There's no quick-n-easy solution for this other than borrowing some library (if one exists).

Comment: You can use NSExpressions for this!

Comment: you can also try [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Xcode 8.3.1 • Swift 3.1**

```
extension String {
    var expression: NSExpression {
        return NSExpression(format: self)
    }
}

let a = 5
let b = 2
let intDictionary = ["a": a,"b": b]

var formula = "a * b"
if let timesResult = formula.expression.expressionValue(with: intDictionary, context: nil) as? Int {  
    print(timesResult) // 10
}
formula = "(a + b) / 2"
if let intAvgResult = formula.expression.expressionValue(with: intDictionary, context: nil) as? Int {
    print(intAvgResult)    // 3
}



let x = 5.0
let y = 2.0
let z = 3.0

let doubleDictionary = ["x": x, "y": y, "z": z]


formula = "(x + y + z) / 3"
if let doubleAvgResult = formula.expression.expressionValue(with: doubleDictionary, context: nil) as? Double {
    print(doubleAvgResult)
}
```

Comment: Hi Leo - I have defined an overloaded operator * to operate on my custom objects (kind of multiplying two or more of them together). For example, here I have two variables A and B:  var A:MyCustomClass = A:MyCustomClass(data: data1), and var B:MyCustomClass = B:MyCustomClass(data: data2). It works when I do: var result:MyCustomClass = A * B. But since I will be getting A * B from user in a form of a string, how do I covert the string "A * B" into variables A * B so the overloaded operator can be fired? Will NSExpression help in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: @appFormation the comments area it is not meant for questions. Feel free to open a new question, post the related code there and if you would like me to take a loot at it just leave the question link here in a comment

Comment: done. Please see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382761/swift-how-to-convert-a-string-into-variables-to-used-with-overloaded-operator)

Comment: @appFormation if you don't post how you are trying to implement your expression and custom operator it will be impossible to help you. BTW it is Swift convention to name your vars starting with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 7):

Use `NSExpression`.

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"4 + 5 - 2**3"];
id value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]; // => 1
```

Expression creation is formatted, so you can input your params as part of the equation.

More info [here](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/).

Answer (score 2):

@Leo for Swift 3 (as opposed to obj-c) in Xcode 8 it would look like this:

```
let mathExpression = NSExpression(format: "4 + 5 - 2**3")
let mathValue = mathExpression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? Int
```

Comment: Very easy to wrap this in a function:func eval(_ s: String) -> Double?