# How can I evaluate bool/arithmetic expression in Swift?

Tags: swift

How can I eval a string in Swift?
My strings are composed by numbers and logic operators.

Some examples are:

```
"2+2"
"2%2" 
"2+2"
"2=3"
"2>3"
"2/5"
```

I've thought, if is too complex to write a function to do this, to parse a string and execute that as external process in bin/bash process than read a result. Any ideas?

Other questions, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719180/swift-resolving-a-math-operation-in-a-string), are solution if there are only arithmetics operators. In my cases appears bool operators that returns error in NSExpression eval.

Comment: This one is also good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089741/swift-string-formula-into-a-real-calculation?lq=1

Comment: How complex are these expressions going to be?  (And not all of your operators are logic operators.)

Comment: Are you using Cocoa/Cocoa Touch (what platform are you working on)?

Comment: This expressions are like n [+, -, *, /, %, =, <, >, **] m, with n, m Integer and one operator in set.

Comment: I'm using Cocoa. NSExpression initializer with bool operator returns SIGABRT error. `let x = NSExpression(format: "2=2")`