# I don't know how to make them add or subtract, its there a way to do so. Basically I want 1"+"3 = 4 but I get 1+3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, concatenation

```
let randsign = Int(arc4random_uniform(2) + 1)

//This function returns a random operator
func whatSign(par1:Int)-> String {

    if (par1 == 1){
        return "+"

    }
    else {
        return "-"
    }

}

var sigh = whatSign(par1: randsign)

let randnum1:Any = Int (arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)
let randnum2:Int = Int (arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)
```

//I want the variable "finVal" to perform mathematical operation, but it does not because the variable "sign" is String

```
let finVal = "\(randnum1)\(sigh)\(randnum2)"
print(finVal)   

//When I print I get for example 1-3, 9-4, 8+2 .But I wanted them to do arithmetic
```

Comment: I dont even understand what the question is... please give more  details on expected input and output...

Comment: When your write anything into  " " inverted commas then it is taken as string. It is not taken as arithmetic sign

Comment: @JeckyModi is there a way so that I can change into an arithmetic sign?

Comment: below is answer @Jenny

Comment: Also: [Swift string formula into a real calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089741/swift-string-formula-into-a-real-calculation).

Comment: @MartinR I did not know about it, at time of asking, I am sorry. What should I do now then ??

Answer (score 3):

[`NSExpression`](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/) is one the good way to evaluate the Math

```
let finVal = "(randnum1)(sigh)(randnum2)" 
let result = NSExpression(format: finVal).expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! Int
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let randsign = Int(arc4random_uniform(2) + 1)
let randnum1:Any = Int (arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)
let randnum2:Int = Int (arc4random_uniform(10) + 1)
var finVal:Int
//This function returns a random operator
func whatSign(par1:Int)-> String {
//I want to compute the variables and get final result from adding or subtracting them
if (par1 == 1){
 finVal = randnum1 + randnum2
    return "+"

}
else {
 finVal = randnum1 - randnum2
    return "-"
}

}

whatSign(par1: randsign)


print(finVal) 
//When I print I get for example 1-3, 9-4, 8+2 .But I wanted them to do arithmetic
```

Maybe it will helps you